# Convert large file to base64 representation in Java; OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: java, base64

I have a situation in which I need to transmit an object from back-end to front-end in this format:

```
{
    filename: "filename",
    type: "type",
    src: "src",
    bytes: "base64Representation"
}
```

The bytes property of the object consists in the base64 representation of a file stored in a repository in the remote server. Up until now I've worked with small files in the range 1-2MB and the code for converting a file to the corresponding base64 representation has worked correctly. But now I'm facing some problems with big files, larger than 100MB. I've checked solutions that try to convert the file chunk by chunk, but still at the end of the process I need all the chunks concatenated in a string and at this step I'm getting an **OutOfMemory** exception.  I've also seen some suggestions to use **OutputStreams**, but I can't apply them because I need the data in the above format. Please does anyone have any suggestions on how can I bypass this situation?

Comment: Increase the size of the heap when you launch the JVM.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca disagree, as this solution won't scale

Comment: @user902383 agree (with you, I mean)

Comment: Instead of reassemblying it, why don't you just stream the chunks to the front-end each time you create one?

Comment: how file is requested? if file is requested by rest request you should get stream where you write file. All what you need to do is to write your chunks into that stream.  provide minimum viable code, and we can guide you

Comment: Dont build a string on your side, stream the base64 representation directly to the outputstream

Comment: Even with continuous writing and streams the HTTP request might timeout for large files or a client buffer may overflow. To support arbitrary sizes of resources, HTTP supports range requests for a specific range (offset, number) of bytes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests

Comment: I'm working on a legacy project where the mvc is created using struts2. The request for downloading the above object is sent through ajax and the server is supposed to respond with a json object. This is the registered action in struts2: <action name="downloadBase64Representation" class="DownloadFileAction" method="downloadBase64Representation">
   <result type="json" name="success">
    <param name="root">result</param>
   </result>
  </action>

Comment: I'm not very sure about streams and how to use them when combining struts2 and ajax requests

Comment: If you're unable to change the way the HTTP request is built you indeed have to serialize the object as a whole - with the potential problems already mentioned above.

Comment: did you try sending these "filename,type,src" in header and use OutputStreams to send actual object

Comment: @Keaz when I tried writing the object in the output stream the front-end got blocked, I mean the result could not be printed in the console. I'm not sure if this comes from limitations on the amount of data that can printed in the console or the result is not being written correctly in the stream

Answer (score 1):

You can use OutputStream and process on the fly in a servlet by wrapping `response.getOutputStream()`. I will give a working example with spring boot. I tested and it works.

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Base64;

@RestController
public class Base64Controller {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/base64", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getBase64File(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        OutputStream wrap = Base64.getEncoder().wrap(response.getOutputStream());
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("./temp.txt");
        int bytes;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        while ((bytes=fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            wrap.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
        }
        fis.close();
        wrap.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A JSON response is a kludge here, with Base64 having a payload of 6/8th per byte, you have 33% more data transfer as needed. Indeed a JSON DOM object is overstretching both the server as also the client side.

So convert it to a simple binary download, and stream it out; possibly throttled for large data.

This means a change in the API.

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with struts, so i'm not sure will this work, but it should be something like that

```
public class DownloadB64Action extends Action{

    private final static BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

   @Override
   public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
     HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     throws Exception {

     response.setContentType("text/plain");

     try 
     {

        FileInputStream in = 
            new FileInputStream(new File("myfile.b64"));

        ServletOutputStream out = Base64.getEncoder().wrap(response.getOutputStream());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        while(in.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE) != -1){
            out.write(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
        }
        in.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();

     }catch(Exception e){
        //TODO handle exception
   }

   return null;
  }
}
```

to make it JSON structure like you need, you might try to write directly to `response.getOutputStream()`  `"{\"filename\":\"filename\",\"type\":\"type\",\"src\":\"src\",\"bytes\": \"".getBytes()` before b64 payload and `"\"}".getBytes()` after

}